# What will happen if leave "developer payload" as blank Google Play In-app Billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Well I have read lots of time about "developer payload" But I am not clearly understand, what for  "developer payload" used for. So I am trying to use this as blank like this:

```
    public void onUpgradeAppButtonClicked(String SKU) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Upgrade button clicked; launching purchase flow for upgrade.");

    /*
     * TODO: for security, generate your payload here for verification. See
     * the comments on verifyDeveloperPayload() for more info. Since this is
     * a SAMPLE, we just use an empty string, but on a production app you
     * should carefully generate this.
     */
    String payload = "";

    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU, RC_REQUEST,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
}
```

And this:

```
boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
    String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
    return true;
}
```

So I have make a image. for 3 Situations. I want to learn what will happen after condition

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your diagram relates to the question. Can you clarify what the diagram part is asking for?

Comment: Well at diagram there are 3 situations. I am asking that what will happen if userY buy a product at those three situations. First one if userY opened my app in different device with same account.  Second if another user use my app in same device with different account. Third one are there any related between any each users

Comment: I see. There are maybe two different notions of user.  There is the user for Google Play whose Google account the item is associated with.  Your app might have a separate notion of user. Which are you talking about?

Comment: Situation 1: User does not need to buy again, because the purchase information are stored on the server.

Comment: If you want to keep the same behavior using the developer payload, you probably would need to store that payload in your own server.

Comment: I had to remove this verify as I always got null for the payload in my tests. Google play doesn't seem to store the payload I send with: inappbillingHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_SWORD, RC_REQUEST,
                    mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);

Comment: how to handle situation 1 in the above mentioned case ?

Comment: @Damnum I have implemented inapp billing in my application with blank payload. Then I created Situation 1, as mentioned above. I have purchased the application in device 1 with email id abc@xyz.com and when I am checking in another device 2 with same email id, the application is asking again to purchase the premium feature again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the most possible shit occurs at scenario 2.

But how many users are on scenario 2? I think it would be not many. Most people don't share their devices.

But I'm thinking about another crack possibility if this payload string left empty. It would be easy to crack it down.

The only thing makes me mad is this thing should be on Google API side. Google's job to verify and make sure who purchased the item. Why we need our own server?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass in a string token that helps your application to identify the user who made the purchase, so that you can later verify that this is a legitimate purchase by that user.

Think of this as a receipt. If a customer came in and wanted to return an item or warranty, you'd want to be darned sure that receipt wasn't printed at home.  Using this token will help prevent fraud.

Answer (score 1):

It's not required, but it is advised.  According to the docs you can send an empty string, though I'm not sure about null.  It's advisable for security reasons though. You can use the payload to verify that the purchase was made by the user that you intended, for instance. See the billing [Security Best Practices](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html#payload)

Comment: What you think about my diagram.  For my tree situations,  I wrote my thought at the right side. Is that true